# Perl: regex to cut the words enclosed in parenthesis

Tags: regex, perl

I have an array @WIALOG_lines, with below entries

```
(0552) -*--@  "<No comment>" 27-Oct-2020 10:40 AM
(0553) M---$ user1 100900 "Random job
(0554) ----@  1119996 "patch content"
(0562) -*--@  "<No comment>" 24-Oct-2020 10:40 AM
```

I need to have 0552,0553,0554 and 0562 in this array. I am trying out the below command and is not working. Can you help with regex to get the values enclosed in parenthesis only.

```
 s/(^[^\(]+")|("[^\)]+)//g for @WIALOG_lines;
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you having?

Comment: Updated the question with what I have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to match the numbers between the first set of parentheses.  That pattern is an open paren, any number of characters that are not a closing paren, and the final paren.  And we want to capture the characters between the parenthesis.  Parenthesis are special in regex, so they need to be escaped.  That regex pattern is:  `m/\(([^)]*)\)/`, where the escaped parentheses match literally, and the other pair of parentheses is a capture group.

Then we want to apply that pattern to each line of the original array, which suggests using a map block. For each element of the original array, do the match and return the matching part. `$1` will be the string that matches the first capture group.

```
my @key = map { m/\(([^)]+)\)/; $1 } @WIALOG_lines;
```

Comment: @Ras Are you reading the file line by line or did you slurp the file into a single variable

Comment: TLP, I am reading line by line. All I missed pushing new entries into @WIALOG_lines. Now, I am good.

Comment: `map { m/\(([^)]+)\)/ }` is good enough. In fact, it's better because it does add `undef` for lines that don't match

Answer (score 0):

A solution to posted question, as was indicated earlier, is easy to implement by capturing digits in brackets to store them in an array for further processing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @keys = map { $1 if /^\((\d+)\)/ } <DATA>;

say for @keys;

__DATA__
(0552) -*--@  "<No comment>" 27-Oct-2020 10:40 AM
(0553) M---$ user1 100900 "Random job
(0554) ----@  1119996 "patch content"
(0562) -*--@  "<No comment>" 24-Oct-2020 10:40 AM
```

More interesting case would be if input data required some additional parsing. Following example demonstrates this approach.

NOTE: input data for record with label *0553* is missing closing `"`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %log;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my @col = /\((\d+)\)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)\z/;
    my $data;
    if( $col[2] =~ /(.*) (\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}) (\d{2}:\d{2}) (\w{2})\z/ ) {
        $data = { comment => $1, date => $2, time => $3, AM => $4 };
    } else {
        $data = { user => $1 , label => $2, desc => $3 } if $col[2] =~ /(\S+) (\d+) (".*?"?)\z/;
        $data = {              label => $1, desc => $2 } if $col[2] =~ /(\d+) (".*?")\z/;
    }
    $log{$col[0]} = { perm => $col[1], data => $data };
}

say Dumper(\%log);

__DATA__
(0552) -*--@  "<No comment>" 27-Oct-2020 10:40 AM
(0553) M---$ user1 100900 "Random job
(0554) ----@  1119996 "patch content"
(0562) -*--@  "<No comment>" 24-Oct-2020 10:40 AM
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          '0562' => {
                      'perm' => '-*--@',
                      'data' => {
                                  'date' => '24-Oct-2020',
                                  'AM' => 'AM',
                                  'comment' => '"<No comment>"',
                                  'time' => '10:40'
                                }
                    },
          '0553' => {
                      'perm' => 'M---$',
                      'data' => {
                                  'desc' => '"Random job',
                                  'user' => 'user1',
                                  'label' => '100900'
                                }
                    },
          '0552' => {
                      'perm' => '-*--@',
                      'data' => {
                                  'date' => '27-Oct-2020',
                                  'time' => '10:40',
                                  'AM' => 'AM',
                                  'comment' => '"<No comment>"'
                                }
                    },
          '0554' => {
                      'data' => {
                                  'label' => '1119996',
                                  'desc' => '"patch content"'
                                },
                      'perm' => '----@'
                    }
        };
```